# charging two 3.6V phone batteries connected in series from a lower voltage source

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging, oscillator

This is a circuit I found on the web at http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/SolarLight/SolarCharger.html that claims that a 12 volt battery can be charged using a smaller power source.

My power source is 6V DC adapter and I want to charge a 7.2V DC power source (2 3.6V batteries connected in series to make 7.2V)

The site states that I need a specific number of turns for each coil winding.

How would I adapt this circuit to charge 7.2V from a 6V power supply and most importantly, how do I calculate the coil values (looking for inducor values in uH) for optimal charge?

Or should I try a different oscillator design? The website did state this design is an oscillator.

And is there a way to add an LED to the circuit that only turns on to indicate complete charge?

I want to eventually take the charging information into a microcontroller, but for now I want to make the charger work.

[image: circuit]

Comment: what battery technology are you looking at, lead acid or Li-Ion?

Comment: I believe nimh or nicad.